# Django reverse url blank

Tags: django, django-urls

What is wrong with the following code below? I don't get any errors, however the href is blank (must be failing silently).

**HTML:**

```
 <a href="{{ item.content_object.get_delete_url }}">
  Remove
 </a>
```

**Model Method:**

```
def get_delete_url(self):
    return reverse('contacts.views.contact_delete', args=[str(self.id), str(self.group_id)])
```

**URL:**

```
url(r'^contact/delete/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<group_id>\d+)/$', 'contact_delete', name='contact_delete'),
```

Comment: Did you try printing the url out in the console?

Comment: @limelights yep, it's blank. the error seems to be in the get_delete_url method, if I change the return to say "something" and print, I see it. So it must be a silent fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_delete_url` method is raising a `NoReverseMatch` exception. The `NoReverseMatch` exception has `silent_variable_failure=True`, so the method fails silently when you use it in the template. See the [Django variables and lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) docs for more info about silent failures in the template.

To fix your `get_delete_url` method, try using the url pattern name that you specified, instead of the path to the view.

```
reverse('contact_delete', args=[str(self.id), str(self.group_id)])
```